# Reading all data from a USB GPS instead of listening to the COM port

Tags: c#, gps, serial-port

I'm writing a C# program that reads data from a USB GPS logger, which acts like a new COM port when i plug it in. I've managed to write some code that listens to the COM port and fires an event when it receives data, but i have a few problems with this approach :

1. The event listener is way to slow : i get like only 1 result per second which takes forever if there are thousands of tracks on the logger.
2. Since i don't know how much data the logger contains, how do i know when i should stop the event listener, without losing data? I would also like to write all the data to a csv file, but since i dont know when to stop listening, i also don't know when to call my writer function.

I actually don't understand why this happens over a COM port, since the logger already contains all the data i need? I just want to extract it all at once. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is not much you can do about this.
You can't change the behavior of the USB device, since this is a driver issue.
The reason it is recognized as a COM port is probably because the manufacturer who made the device didn't want to have to deal with the devious task of writing drivers for the device.

So instead he used a chip that translates the data from the microchip to "Serial communiation", to emulate RS-232 communication. Which is far easier to handle. Also for you, because you probably wouldn't be able to read the data or interact with a Custom USB device without proper documentation..

The normal baud rate for RS-232 is usual 9600. This would be minimal 9600 Bits per Second.
So thinking it could be a 8 or 16 bit device, this would result in 1200 or 600 integers per minute.
So depending on the data you read per result, i think 1 result/second is rather slow.

Hope this is of any help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If i communicate with the COM port, how do i know when i've read all the data, and i can stop listening?

Comment: This is also defined in the Microchip of the GPS device. Without any documentation this is hard to tell..  You might look at wether the device keeps repeating the same record over and over. This might be a good indication. Or if it just stops sending data.

Comment: And are you sure it just isn't transmitting the current location when you plug it in? Because that is my experience with such devices. They only start sending the log's after recieving a certain command.

Comment: I'm using a canway GT-730FL-S, but i can't find much useful documentation. The logger comes with it's own software tool, which imports all the data in a few seconds. So i'm guessing it can be done one way or another. Perhaps you can point me in a direction on sending commands to a COM port? I'm very new to this.

Comment: Since i can't find documentation about possible commands, is there a way to "ask" the device for a command overview?

Comment: Tim, Trying to communicate with a pheriphical device, without any documentation is like trying to crack a safe. You can try trial and error. Try to send keywords like, start, stop, continue, read, start_read, Start_log etc.. and see how the device responds, if it responds at all..
But as i said, it's something i wouldn't even try, unless the MCU holds somekind of million dollar secret.
What you can try is to program your own MCU, and replace the onboard one.. Or buy some generic tracker WITH documentation?

Comment: Perhaps you know about a gps device which allows me to simply extract the data, just like a usb stick?